# Match unity coordinate system to another coordinate system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, coordinate-systems, hololens

I am working on a project where I have a positioning layout tool (station), that sends out a laser pointer, and when that laser pointer hits a reflector, it gives me the X,Y and Z coordinates of the reflector, including distance, horizontal and vertical angle of the station. this station has it's own coordinate system, is the starting position and these values are relative to it.

What I want to do is, read the (x,y,z) values from that station, and display them as points or objects in the Hololens view using unity3D. The issue is, that I have two different coordinate systems, the unity coordinate system that starts at (0,0,0) when the app starts, and the station's coordinate system that starts from the station itself. 
What I did is, I spawned 3 known points in the Hololens space, which I want to reference with the station, I check the coordinates of these 3 points in reference to the station, then I have 6 overlapping points coming from different sources, and using matrices, I try to find the position and rotation of the station in the hololens space.

This is a rough drawing of what I want to achieve:

[image: Different Coordinate Systems with overlapping points]

On the right is the station and on the left is the hololens, X1 X2 and X3 are the coordinates I get from the station relative to the stations origin, these x y and z coordinates, along with a vertical and horizontal angle, are the result of the laser pointer leaving the station and hitting the reflector.
The X1' X2' and X3' are the points relative to the hololens space, with those points overlapping, but with different coordinates, I want to get the origin of X1 X2 and X3 in the hololens space, which is the station's position.

Is there any way I could achieve this better? Where I can find the position of this station in the hololens space, having other point coordinates coming from that station and relative to it?

Comment: What does this station looks like? Can you place a marker on it?

Comment: The station looks something like this: https://www.buildingpointpacific.com/sites/default/files/product-images/RTS573_0.jpg
I tried with Vuforia to track the position of the station, but it's not accurate enough and does not fulfill the need of the app.

Comment: You can simply use [Transform.InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) and [Transform.TransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) to convert local coordinates to worldspace coordinates and the other way round.

Comment: Please add the code you use for placing stuff in Unity

Comment: Well my idea was to place the marker and create an empty object at marker position and rotation relative to your station. Then you can use station coordinate system you will not need any transformation. Also how much of an accuracy are you talking about? You have to use Hololens for detecting 3 common points how accurate is it at detecting those points? Also you can take a look at [this](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671)

Comment: Could you add some legends on the picture? it's too abstract. where is the station, reflector, laser, which one is hololens space, whichi one is x axis. and where is the origin?

Comment: @AliKanat I found your similar issue on stackoverflow with the ARCore, it looks similar to my problem, the only thing that I did not understand is how to get/calculate the translation vector and rotation matrix?
I need an accuracy of not more than 2cm, I think I can achieve that with a marker, but my use case needs an out of the box conversion.

Comment: @shingo  please see my edited picture and an explanation.

Comment: Well you can use the method in the link i sent you aka Rigid Transform which gives you a rotation matrix and a translation vector. Then you can convert it to Unity 4x4 Transformation matrix and apply it to any point you want. For  calculating R and t you need 3 common points anyway either marker or another method you found. Then your accuracy depends on how accurate Hololens tracks those positions. I am assuming it will track better than ARCore considering all sensors it has.

Comment: @AliKanat Thank you, I will try it out and get back with feedback.

Comment: I think I understood your basic idea. In my project I also use a marker via Vuforia to track a machine and no deviation larger than half a centimeter is allowed. And I would say that Vuforia works pretty good, it places all needed stuff at the right position. Maybe your light conditions were not so good?

Comment: Hi @DRYRA I am looking at similar problem. Can you please post your solution